# Disambiguating the [gradient] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

As of now, the [gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) tag excerpt says:

> Specifies a range of position-dependent colors, usually used to fill a region.

However, looking at the questions where it appears, we can see two very different uses:

- Graphical gradients (as the tag excerpt suggests), where it is typically accompanied by [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).
- Mathematical gradients (i.e. derivatives of functions), where it is typically accompanied by some scientific language tag or a machine learning tool.

I believe that this situation should be disambiguated in one of the following ways:

1. The [gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) tag is modified to refer to the mathematical sense, and *color*-gradient related questions are retagged with [linear-gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-gradients) or [radial-gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radial-gradients). A note pointing to the color gradients is added to the excerpt.
2. A [mathematical-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-gradient) tag is created and the relevant questions are retagged. A note pointing to mathematical gradients is added to the excerpt of [gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient).

P.S.
Personally, what led me to write this post is that several days ago I wanted to indicate that a question dealt with *mathematical* gradients, but there was no tag available to me. I realize that many askers don't bother reading the excerpt of [gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) and end up using a wrong tag for their e.g. [gradient-descent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient-descent)-related questions.

Comment: Technically speaking a colour gradient is a mathematical gradient, just with colours attached to the numbers. One could think of logarithmic colour scales, step-wise scales or other non-linear gradients, which would make suggestions of the sort too limited. Won't [tag:colour-gradient] work for colour gradients?

Comment: @Adriaan I would guess that the vast majority of those using color gradients is oblivious to the mathematical meaning of the term. For them, it is just a "technical term" for "gradual" (as in a gradual color change). Regardless, I like your suggestion.

Comment: It is not ambiguous, none of the experts in this tag will be helpful to answer your question.  You need the [math] tag, some odds that math.se is the proper site.

Comment: @HansPassant *You need the [math] tag, some odds that math.se is the proper site*. This is plainly not true, and feel free to open another meta question to discuss it. There are thousands of very fitting questions on SO about programming maths. Its the same as saying that anything to do with color gradient should go to graphicdesign.se.

Comment: Pretty typical meta hyperbole, served so well by throwing back only part of a comment.  *some odds* does not mean *absolutely*.  It isn't even good enough to spend money on a lottery ticket :)

Comment: @HansPassant sorry if you think I misinterpreted your comment, but then I do not know what you wanted to contribute on the disambiguation of [color-gradient] vs [math-gradient]. If both are fitting then *I believe* there is ambiguity calling it only [gradient]. I assumed that with your comment you meant to dismiss the usage of [math-gradient] because its for math.se. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Note that [[tag:css-gradients]] already have their own tag.

Comment: There's also [[tag:tensorflow-gradient]], [repeating-linear-gradient], [stochastic-gradient], [linear-gradients], and [radial-gradients] which might have bled into gradient as well. Maybe we should be consistent about plural/singular form for tags. :-/

Comment: It's an auxiliary tag. Maybe it's not ideal that the tag alone lacks clarity, but when paired with other tags, its ambiguity is quickly lost I can imagine. How many questions are there with only one tag, where that tag is 'gradient'?